# How to make a whole node teaser with a View inside clickable?

Tags: 7, views, theming, nodes

I overrode my node's template file, such that my node teasers are clickable and redirect to the full node page. Now, I also have a View that displays some user fields (without links) and I would like to display this View in the node teaser. I added `<?php print views_embed_view('my_view', 'default', $uid); ?>` between the teaser fields:

```
<div id="teaser">
  <a href="<?php print url('node/' . $node->nid); ?>">
    <div id="teaser-header">
      <span class="teaser-title"><?php print $title; ?></span>
    </div>

    <div id="teaser-content">
      <span class="teaser-image">
        <?php print render($content['field_image']); ?>
      </span>

      <?php print views_embed_view('my_view', 'default', $uid); ?>

      <div class="teaser-statistics">
        <span>(<?php print $comment_count; ?>)</span>
        <?php $flag = flag_get_flag('my_flag'); ?>
        <span>(<?php print $flag->get_count($nid); ?>)</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

The View displays fine, but the whole teaser is not clickable anymore: the anchor wraps correctly around `teaser-header`, but not around the View's `div`.

Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

Comment: Just a side note: You're missing a `/` should be `<a href="<?php print url('/node/' . $node->nid); ?>">`

Comment: That's not right, router paths don't have a leading `/`. The code in your OP using `url` is already correct, don't change it or you'll be introducing a second problem

Comment: @NoSssweat Clive right, and also he code in Drupal 7 , this is correct in drupal 7.
Jeroen would you please come your complete code here ? ( I mean your snippet with view render.

Comment: This is a classic case of divitis - you don't need a div to be clickable, just give the <a> tag a class. Then edit the CSS of the class to display:block, and define a height and width.  Divities explaination can be found on http://csscreator.com/divitis

Comment: @Justme: Let's focus on the real problem for a moment. `#teaser` doesn't have a fixed height, so how should I define the height for `a`? Setting it to `100%` doesn't work.

Comment: Setting it to 100% only fits if one of the upper container is defined, so if you can defined a upper div above #teaser as fixed it would probably work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [Stefanos Petrakis' answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/213093/16550), I checked something that I should have done before. There actually *is* a link in my View: the contextual link trigger! Once I logged out as an admin, these links disappeared (anonymous users don't have permission to use them) and the teasers were clickable as desired. Therefore, my real problem was: *How can I disable the contextual links for my specific View?*

Of course, this is very easily done: go to your View's section *Other* and change the *Hide contextual links* option to *Yes*. Mind that [Benia's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/213099/16550) won't work, because the anchor tag will still be there, although one won't see it.

Answer (score 2):

Some detective work is needed here, the prime suspect is - as you already mentioned - the HTML generated by the views_embed_view.
Without getting a look at what that looks like, it's just a guess game.

But... it could vey well be that your view's HTML is also containing some anchor tags. In other words, you have **nested links** in you HTML, which could very well explain the problem you are experiencing.

Some refs:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13054959/5875098
- https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2

Good luck!

Comment: I found the reason for my problem and gave you an upvote for your hint.